# Is there a component wise characterisation of open maps just like in continuous maps?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $\mathscr{A}$ is any indexing set, and let $\prod_{\alpha\in\mathscr{A}} Y_{\alpha}$ be the product space of non-empty topological spaces $Y_{\alpha}$.

The question is this: let $X$ be any topological space. There is a very well-known fact that a map $f:X\to\prod Y_{\alpha}$ is continuous if and only if each *co-ordinate* map $p_{\beta}\circ f$ is continuous, where $\beta\in\mathscr{A}$. I wondered if the following is also true:

> A map $f:X\to\prod Y_{\alpha}$ is *open* if and only if each component
> map is open.

I thought of this while trying to prove a notationally difficult proof; if this statement turns out to be true, then the proof would become easier. It is easy to see that one-direction of this is true.

I have not been able to prove the other direction. Is there a counter-example to this? If not, please give only a hint to proving it.

Comment: If $f$ is open, $f \circ p_\alpha$ is open, as composition of open maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One direction is trivial, as all projections are open and compositions of open maps are open.

The other direction is wrong: take $X=\Bbb R$, $Y=\Bbb R^2$, $f(x)=(x,x)$ is not open while $\pi_i \circ f$ ($i=1,2$) is the identity and thus open.

Answer (score 1):

The map $f:\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R^2:x\mapsto\left\langle x,\frac1x\right\rangle$ is not open, but its compositions with the projection maps from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$ are open.